# Number Algorithm for Barcodes

Tags: c#, algorithm, barcode

I'm having these kind of serial codes that should print in a ID card as a barcode but the problem is barcode of these numbers is larger than the ID card width.

- 9913010001CHEREV0215
- 9913010002CHEREV0215
- 9913010003CHEREV0215
- 9913010004CHEREV0215

Is there any possibility to reduce the number of the digits by using an algorithm to generate a fix number of digits,

Ex- for the above numbers there are 20 characters and using an algorithm it can be reduced in to 10 characters .

not only that I need to reverse the original code (20 characters ) from the above barcoded code(10 character code) .

Is there any algorithm to achieve this from C#?

Comment: better use a smaller barcode font... (thinner lines --> smaller barcode)

Comment: Is the `CHEREV0215` part constant? If so, you can just remove that, and the barcoded number will just be the first 10 digits.

Comment: need more info about how your number is varying and what is constant.

Comment: You can do what @RB is suggested and look for constants in the codes and remove those.  If you are looking for a hasing algorithm to reduce the size of the string them I'm afraid they are one way only.  So although they will reduce the size of the string, you won't be able to get the original string back, so that wouldn't be an option.

Comment: CHEREV0215 is not a constant , It's a batch code. 
First two digits are Institute ID. 
Then a time stamp(year/month)and a personal ID number(4 digits), and finally the batch code(10 digits)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not really an algorithm behind barcodes. Most barcodes are just a sequence of lines, where each couple of lines represents a character. Barcodes are often acquired by just printing the text in a special barcode font.

**Printing smaller**:
You can either print it smaller, or use a different type of barcode. Note however that not all types of barcodes support all those characters. Some support the entire alphabet, while others support only numbers.

Also, there's a limit of how small you can print it. For most barcodes there are official guidelines of minimum size, minimum printing resolution and minimum amount of whitespace that needs to be open around the barcode.

Dropping below those limits will affect the readability of your barcode, make it harder for the people using them. But you can get away by removing a millimeter or two of the height, and if your paper quality is good and the printing resolution is high enough, you may get away with a little smaller.

**Reducing string length**:
Reducing the length of the string is a possibility, but remember that you [cannot shorten every 20 byte string to 10 bytes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle). If you got specific knowledge about the string, you could use that. For instance if 'CHEREV' is a constant part, one could wonder if it should be part of the barcode at all. [edit] Initially I overlooked the comment where you said it isn't constant.

**Numbers only**:
Alphabetic barcodes have more characters and therefor are usually wider. If you could change your batch code text to a number, then you could use a narrower numbers-only barcode.